# div shown instantly on revisit

Tags: javascript, cookies

On my page I've added DIV with a time delayed content.
The content will obviously not be shown until the timer runs out.
See code code below.

Now the issue is that I would like to show the div instantly on
revisiting the page (perhaps by cookie?).

Unfortunately this coding is too complex for me and I was hoping anyone could help me out... (JSfiddle prefered)

Thanks in advance if you can help me out!

```js
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("optin").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 2000); // after 110 sec (1m50s)
```

```html
HEY 
<div id="optin" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <p>You can only see this after the timer runs out!</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not really complex...Create cookie...Read cookie...Do the conditional stuff...

Comment: Better with sessionStorage or localStorage than a cookie, for this purpose is less code, better performance.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, Right!...@OP, refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/vu26prtn/

Answer (score 0):

for your timer

```
setTimeout("showIt()", 2000); // after 110 sec (1m50s)
```

2000 is 2000ms, 2 seconds. you want 110000 for 110 seconds.

As far as setting the session variable:

```
//checks to make sure the browser supports session storage 
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    //checks to see if the current session variable exists
    if (localStorage.pageVisited) {
        //display the element
        document.getElementById('optin').style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        //creates the pageVisited session variable
        localStorage.pageVisited = 1;
    }
}
```